# In Rails, how do I export to CSV while translating values of a specific column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

Currently, I'm using Rails and able to export, but there are values within the DB that are in a numeric format, and I need them to be translated into an alphanumeric format. I have the translations, but I don't know how to do it while exporting to CSV

Here's my current snippet of code to export to CSV

```
def self.to_csv(mycolumns)
  CSV.generate() do |csv|
    csv << mycolumns
    all.each do |ccts|
      csv << ccts.attributes.values_at(*mycolumns)
    end
  end
end
```

So my initial thought was that I could go into each ccts and edit them, but I don't know how to access the value within the hash and alter it. And it's only for a specific column. For instance, if this table was for fruits, and one of the column names was `Name`. If I wanted to change a value of `0041` into `Apple`, but only within the Name column, I'm just not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: We need more information, like what are the values being returned by `values_at(*mycolumns)`? When debugging it helps to write a small test script that doesn't hit the database, but instead uses a small internal array that replicates the DB contents. Then you can write your code to walk that array and change the values and output the CSV. Then, once you have that working you fold that code into the code that walks the database.

Answer (score 0):

The csv export code is very compact, especially this line:

```
csv << ccts.attributes.values_at(*mycolumns)
```

That makes it difficult to think about how to change it.

First think how you would export your value if it was a single column. It may look something like:

```
if column_name == :name
  lookup_fruit_name(ccts.name)
else
  ccts[column_name]
end
```

Now you need all the values of a `ccts` inside an array, so it can be sent to csv:

```
values = mycolums.map do |column_name|
  if column_name == :name
    lookup_fruit_name(ccts.name)
  else
    ccts[column_name]
  end
end
csv << values
```

Then just place this inside the inner loop of your original export method.

If you think more functional, you just write an instance method that gets your value and does a conversion depending on the column:

```
def csv_value_for(column_name)
  if column_name == :name
    lookup_fruit_name( self.name )
  else
    self[column_name]
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
csv << mycolumns.map{|col| ccts.csv_value_for(col) }
```